# When is Clojure's Birthday?

Tags: clojure

I am giving a presentation and I would like to know when Clojure was officially released.  Also, so I know when to send the Birthday Card :)

Comment: This could probably be interesting for you: http://www.slideshare.net/thnetos/clojure-intro

Comment: voted to re-open as this seems a perfectly reasonable and objectively answerable question about "software tools commonly used by programmers" as per the FAQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The earliest public release [*I know of*] is [**September 22nd, 2007**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clojure/files/clojure/20070922/). The article [Clojure is Two!](http://clojure.blogspot.com/2009/10/clojure-is-two.html) (from October 16th, 2009) backs this up as "being the birth" of Clojure (although there were a number of dated releases in short succession thereafter).

Additionally [the Clojure 1.0 annoncement](http://clojure.blogspot.com/2009/05/clojure-10.html) from May 4th, 2009 says "...Clojure represents several years of effort on my part, but has also been shaped profoundly by the community *in the 18 months since its release to the public.*" This reinforces the September-October 2007 birth-date and implies that Clojure caused a somewhat long "pregnancy" :-)

Happy coding.